# Product of binomial coefficients - why isn't this the right answer?

Tags: self-study

Question from "Introduction to Probability", Blitzstein-Hwang:

> To fulfill the requirements for a degree students have to take any 7 of 20 courses with the constraint that 1 course has to be a statistics course. Of the 20 courses 5 are statistics courses.
> a) How many choices are there for the 7 courses? 
> b) Explain why the answer to a) is *not* (5 choose 1) x (19 choose 6).

I can't think of any other solution than (5 choose 1) x (19 choose 6) - can someone pls tell me what the right answer is and why (5 choose 1) x (19 choose 6) is incorrect?

Comment: The problem is that there aren't 19 non-statistics courses: there are only 15 of them.

Comment: @whuber Why do you think the remaining 6 courses must be non-statistics courses?

Comment: @Trynna That's an interpretation.  There can be others, as you suggest--but unfortunately your answer is not a correct answer to any of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ${5\choose 1}{15 \choose 6}$ ways to choose *exactly one* statistics course. My guess is that the requirement may be to choose *at least one.*

Ways to choose 7 from among 20 without restriction is ${20\choose 7};$
ways to choose all non-statistics courses is ${15 \choose 7}.$

$${20\choose 7} = {5\choose 0}{15\choose 7}+{5\choose 1}{15\choose 6}+\cdots +{5\choose 5}{15\choose 2}.$$

In R:

```
choose(20, 7)
[1] 77520
sum(choose(5, 0:5)*choose(15, 7:2))
[1] 77520
```

Addendum:  Also consider

```
choose(20,7) - choose(15,7)
[1] 71085
sum(choose(5, 1:5)*choose(15, 6:2))
[1] 71085
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Bruce. Yes, I also interpreted the question as "at least one stats course". What is the solution for that scenario?

Comment: Add the relevant possibilities or subtract the forbidden one from the total. See Addendum.

Comment: I guess you'll study **hypergeometric distributions** soon. Then you can answer this question: "If a student never talks to an adviser and takes seven courses at random, what is the probability (s)he meets the requirement." `1 - dhyper(0, 5,15, 7)`

Comment: Thank you very much, @BruceET.